# Excel VBA: Copy Row from another workbook and paste into master workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have many excel files of the same structure in one folder (Test01, Test02, Test03).

I created another excel file in the same folder that needs to pull out information from each other excel file (Results).

There is a specific column in each Test file that I need to copy and paste into a row in the Results file.

I am trying to create a tool or Macro that can, from a push of a button, extract the same column from each file and paste it into a new row in the Results file.

I cannot alter anything in the Test files and this should be done automatically without opening each file. Also new Test files will be added to the folder (Test04, Test05 etc) so the function should be able to pull from the new files.

[image: VBA of Code and Test01 example]

[image: Results file]

My Code does not run and instead, receives a run time error:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

'Dim info

'info = isWorkBookopen("C:\Users\Ridwan\Desktop\Test_Excel\Test01.xlsm")
'If info = False Then
Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\Ridwan\Desktop\Test_Excel\Test01.xlsm"
'End If

Worksheets(Sheet2).Activate  'This is giving me a runtime error

Range("C2:C10").Copy

'Need functions to paste into Results.xlsm

End Sub
```

On a side note, my isWorkBookopen function does not work and it does not recognize it as a function.  This is why I commented those lines.

Comment: Worksheets is expecting a string value`Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate`

Answer (score 1):

Try to make everything explicit

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim wbSource as Workbook
Dim wbTarget as Workbook    
Dim shSource as Worksheet
Dim shTarget as Worksheet

' Open workbook to copy from as readonly
Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\Ridwan\Desktop\Test_Excel\Test01.xlsm", ReadOnly:=true)

' The data is copies to this workbook
Set wbTarget = ThisWorkbook    

' Did you enclose the worksheet name with double quotes?
' Reference to sheet to copy from
set shSource = wbSource.Worksheets("Sheet2")

' Reference to sheet to copy to
set shTarget = wbTarget.Worksheets("Sheet to copy to")

' Copy data to first column in target sheet
shSource.Range("C2:C10").Copy Destination:= shTarget.Cells(1,1)

End Sub
```

This way you do not have to use statements like Activate which are error-prone in some situations.

Comment: Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\khanr1\Desktop\Test_Excel\Results.xlsm")

When I use this line, it is asking me if I want to re-open the file.  If I say yes, it re-opens and the code just loops from the beginning to this line.  If I say 'no' then it gives a run time error.

Comment: My mistake. You run the code from within the Results.xlsm. You do not have to open this workbook. I modify the code. I have changed it into `Set wbTarget = ThisWorkbook`

Comment: Thanks a ton Barry!  Now would you happen to know how I can transpose the column into a row after it has been copied?

Comment: I created another Question, if you are interested here is the link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980532/excel-vba-transpose-a-column-to-a-row

Answer (score 1):

See the different uses for calling sheets :

[image]

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim wB As Workbook
Dim wS As Worksheet

Set wB = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\Ridwan\Desktop\Test_Excel\Test01.xlsm")


Set wS = wB.Sheets("SheetName") 'Name of the sheet in Excel
''OR
'Set wS = wB.Sheet2 'Name that you'll see in VBE in parenthesis

wS.Range("C2:C10").Copy

Dim wB2 As Workbook
Dim wS2 As Worksheet
Dim rG As Range

'if Results.xlsm as already open
Set wB2 = Workbooks("Results.xlsm")
Set wS2 = wB2.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set rG = wS2.Range("B2")
rG.Paste

End Sub
```

Comment: Workbooks("Results.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Paste

This line does not seem to be recognized when I debug it.  I was having the same problem when trying out the code below.  I think "Workbooks" is not being recognized.

Comment: @Ridwan : See the edit, it should help you find the guilty part for the error. Is your workbook `Results.xlsm` already open when you launch the code?

Answer (score 1):

since you said *"this should be done automatically without opening each file."*, you can try this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
    Dim testFolder As Folder
    Dim f As File
    Dim i As Long

    Set testFolder = fso.GetFolder("C:\Users\Ridwan\Desktop\Test_Excel")
    With Worksheets("Results")
        For Each f In testFolder.Files
            If Left(f.Name, 4) = "Test" Then
                If fso.GetExtensionName(f.Path) = "xlsm" Then
                    With .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                        .Value = f.Name
                        i = 0
                        Do
                            i = i + 1
                            .Offset(, i).Formula = "='" & testFolder.Path & "\[" & f.Name & "]Sheet1'!C" & i + 1
                        Loop While .Offset(, i) <> 0
                        .Offset(, i).ClearContents
                        With Range(.Offset(, 1), .Offset(, 1).End(xlToRight))
                            .Value = .Value
                        End With
                    End With
                End If
            End If
        Next f
    End With
End Sub
```

it requires "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" reference to be added to your project (Tool -> References, then scroll down the listbox till you see that library, tick the checkbox at its left and press "OK")