# Excel VBA: Transpose a column to a row

Tags: vba, excel, transpose

I need to transpose my Column to a Row.  I have a code I found that works but it is not doing exactly what I desire.

This is what my file looks like before I run the code:

[image: File Before]

This is what my file looks like after I run the code:

[image: File After]

I want my result to be displayed on the row that the top cell of the column is on.  In this case, I want the column to transpose on the 5th row instead of jumping up to the 1st like you see in the second picture.

This is my Code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim rng As Range
Dim I As Long

    Set rng = Range("B5")
    While rng.Value <> ""
        I = I + 1
        rng.Resize(60).Copy
        Range("C" & I).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
        Set rng = rng.Offset(60)

    Wend
    rng.EntireColumn.Delete
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```
'// source column range
Set rng = Range("B5", Range("B5").End(xlDown))

'// resize from destination cell, transpose
Range("B5").Resize(rng.Columns.Count, rng.Rows.Count).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(rng)

'// clear transposed values
'// offset by 1 to preserve B5
rng.Offset(1, 0).Clear
```